# My Ubuntu is booting to a black screen. What can I do?

Tags: boot, luks

My LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 17.10 install normally would boot to a display that requests a passcode to decrypt the drive and then would boot to the Ubuntu login display. Instead it is now booting just to a black display. I have tried booting it to GRUB by pressing <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> but it then just displays `GRUB loading.` and freezes. I have tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> trick mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/654589), which is listed under the heading "LUKS encryption", to try to get a terminal LUKS dialog for the decryption passcode but this doesn't do anything, and the black display remains, so the solution presented there doesn't work. I can boot to a live USB Ubuntu distribution but I don't know what to do from that.

How can I approach this problem further?

---

EDIT: After a number of attempts at rebooting (which changing nothing manually) they system eventually booted successfully. I have no idea why increasing the number of boot attempts or letting time pass should be able to fix a problem like this, and I'd like to understand this. However, following this, I encountered the problem again (after Ubuntu froze) and again am seeing the black screen on boot.

While the booting was working this time, I followed the suggestion of [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027640/my-ubuntu-is-booting-to-a-black-screen-what-can-i-do#comment1671536_1027640) and managed to record a Boot-Info log from when the boot was succeeding and then subsequently managed to record a Boot-Info log from when the boot was just going to the black screen.

- [Boot-Info log from after a successful boot](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KQcCcNgT4h/)
- [Boot-Info log from after a boot to black screen](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B4MCBG2Xsd/)

I have compared these logs and nothing jumps out at me but perhaps a more trained eye will see something that I don't.

Comment: It looks like LUKS is only mentioned in one answer on the question I linked. So maybe it's not helpful. Then again, maybe this has nothing to do with LUKS. If you feel LUKS is the problem, you might want to edit the title to clarify.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks. Yes, I actually referenced that question in my question, saying that I tried its solution, which doesn't work. Is there some way to get the terminal prompt of LUKS to appear or to force GRUB to load successfully?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added the heading ("LUKS encryption") under which the steps I followed are listed, and I already had those steps described in this question, basically trying to get LUKS to display its dialog in a terminal instead of in a GUI. As mentioned, this didn't work. There is literally only a black display, no terminal output.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have already included these details. I had them in the question originally. As I said, I did <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> as is suggested in the LUKS encryption section of the solution, again which I already referenced. I don't know how to be clearer.

Comment: Alright. Looks like the Grub installation may be broken or misconfigured. Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? I don't know if it can repair encrypted installations but it'll include enough info for me to describe how to do it manually. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for your suggestion. Somehow the system briefly started booting successfully and now is booting to black screen again. Happily I managed to get Boot-Info logs for a successful boot and an unsuccessful boot. I've edited my question with links to the logs. Could you by any chance take a look?

Comment: The Boot-Info output looks fine and the Boot-Info program itself thinks so too. It doesn't hurt to [reinstall Grub](/q/88384/175814) in case we missed something. Can you try that please? Since I don't know how Boot-Repair handles encrypted partitions, I recommend manual methods [like in Scott’s answer](/a/88432/175814). To decrypt LUKS partitions you need to use `sudo cryptsetup open <NAME> <DEVICE> --type LUKS` in step 2 and on success the decrypted partition will appear at `/dev/mapper/<NAME>` to use in step 3. (You can choose `<NAME>` freely.)